# React Redux passing props componentDidMount to useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, use-effect

How would I change componentDidMount(), componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) to useEffect? I just cannot figure it out.

this one below is my code without using Hook.  getting this.props.auth from reducers.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
     this.props.history.push('/main');
  }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.history.push('/main');
        }
}
```

What I want to do here is to use Hook useEffect.  I'm not figuring out how to pass this.props.auth.

```
import React, { useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginPage = () =>{
   const navigate = useNavigate(); 

   //componentDidMount()
   useEffect(() => {
       if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            navigate('/main');
        }
       
   }, [])
   //componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
   useEffect((nextProps) => {
       if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            navigate('/main');
        }
       
   }, )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The react hook equivalent to the previous `componentWillReceiveProps` hook can be the `useEffect` hook, just specify the prop in the dependency array that you want to listen for changes.

From Official React [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> You can think of `useEffect` Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

If you want `useEffect` to be called each time the `auth` prop changes, specify it in the dependency array in `useEffect`.

```
import React, { useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginPage = ({auth, ...rest}) =>{
   const navigate = useNavigate(); 
 
   useEffect(() => {
       if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
            navigate('/main');
        }
       
   }, [auth])

   ... 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the rapid reply. it totally makes sense your code.  Just one quick question tho if you don't mind... the code works but I get a warning sayin "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'navigate'. Either include it or remove the dependency array " is this ok to leave it ? much appreciate your help.

Comment: It's OK if you leave `navigate` out of the dependent array. Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854902